# "Using System.Web.Http" is not supported in .NET Core 6 Class Library. What is the alternative?

Tags: asp.net-core, system.web.http

One of my our application uses `System.Web.Http` to support `ExceptionHandler` in ASP.NET 4.x for the existing code. Currently I am migrating all the class library to .Net 6 Class library. However, `System.Web.Http` nuget package is not available for .NET 6.

Is there any alternative package to support `ExceptionHandler` in .NET 6?

Tried many NuGet package packages. Didn't work out.

Answer (score 1):

The `System.Web.Http` namespace does not exist in the .Net Core 6.
See the documentation: [Migrate from ASP.NET Web API to ASP.NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/webapi?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio)

To migrate to ASP.NET Core:

> Remove using statements for the following ASP.NET 4.x components that
> don't exist in ASP.NET Core:
>
> - `ApiController` class
> - `System.Web.Http` namespace
> - `IHttpActionResult` interface

How to process error exceptions in ASP.NET Core this will depend on your specific case. For more details you can reference to the following article in the Microsoft documentation: [Handle errors in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

---

For example, see the solution provided in the following post: [After upgrading to .Net 6, system.web no longer contains HttpException](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72452332/6630084)