# ASP.NET Core 7 Web API inside Blazor Server project not working

Tags: blazor, asp.net-core-webapi, blazor-server-side, .net-7.0

I am trying to add an ASP.NET Core 7 Web API inside the Blazor Server application, but the API is not loading.

When I go to this URL: `https://localhost:44322/api/GetWeatherForecast`, I see the following. Please let me know how to fix this.

Thanks!

> Sorry, there's nothing at this address.

My API controller:

```
using BlazorAppWebAPI.Data;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace BlazorAppWebAPI.API
{
    [ApiController]
    [System.Web.Http.Route("api")]
    public class APIController : Controller
    {
        private static readonly string[] Summaries = new[]
        {"Freezing", "Bracing", "Chilly", "Cool", "Mild", "Warm", "Balmy", "Hot", "Sweltering", "Scorching"};

        private readonly ILogger<ApiController> _logger;

        public APIController(ILogger<ApiController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.HttpGet("GetWeatherForecast")]
        public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get()
        {
            return Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
            {
                Date = DateOnly.FromDateTime(DateTime.Now.AddDays(index)),
                TemperatureC = Random.Shared.Next(-20, 55),
                Summary = Summaries[Random.Shared.Next(Summaries.Length)]
            })
            .ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

`Program.cs`:

```
using BlazorAppWebAPI.Data;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor();
builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<WeatherForecastService>();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.MapControllers();

app.MapBlazorHub();
app.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");

app.Run();
```

`WeatherForcast.cs`:

```
namespace BlazorAppWebAPI.Data
{
    public class WeatherForecast
    {
        public DateOnly Date { get; set; }

        public int TemperatureC { get; set; }

        public int TemperatureF => 32 + (int)(TemperatureC / 0.5556);

        public string? Summary { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/70586014

Comment: Could you push this sample code to Github repo.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After checking the issue, I found `System.Web.Http` is the root cause. [The System.Web.Http namespace does not exist in the ASP.Net Core](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75121802/7687666).

Here is the correct step to add api in Blazor Server App.

*Program.cs*

```
using BlazorAppWebAPI.Data;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web;

namespace BlazorAppWebAPI
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

            // Add services to the container.
            // add this line
            builder.Services.AddControllers();

            builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
            builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor();
            builder.Services.AddSingleton<WeatherForecastService>();

            var app = builder.Build();

            // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
            if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();
            // add this line
            app.MapControllers();
            app.MapBlazorHub();
            app.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");

            app.Run();
        }
    }
}
```

*APIController.cs*

```
using BlazorAppWebAPI.Data;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace BlazorAppWebAPI.API
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class APIController : ControllerBase
    {
        private static readonly string[] Summaries = new[]
        {"Freezing", "Bracing", "Chilly", "Cool", "Mild", "Warm", "Balmy", "Hot", "Sweltering", "Scorching"};

        private readonly ILogger<APIController> _logger;

        public APIController(ILogger<APIController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        [HttpGet("GetWeatherForecast")]
        public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get()
        {
            return Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
            {
                Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(index),
                TemperatureC = Random.Shared.Next(-20, 55),
                Summary = Summaries[Random.Shared.Next(Summaries.Length)]
            })
            .ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

*Test Result*

[image]