# Base64 pdf is not loading in iframe popup in blazor

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, blazor

If you're encountering issues with loading large PDF files in a Blazor popup, it might be due to limitations in the size of data that can be handled efficiently, especially when using iframe or HTML encoded objects. Loading large files directly into the DOM can sometimes lead to performance issues or even outright failure.

Here is my javascript code block which is called from blazor code behind

Javascript code

```
function openPdf(base64PdfDoc) {
    "use strict";
    var left = window.screen.width;
    left = left > 0 ? left / 4 : 0;
    let pdfWindow = window.open("", 'winname', 'directories=no,titlebar=no,toolbar=no,location=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=no,width=800,height=750, top = 0, left=' + left);
    pdfWindow.document.write(
        "<iframe width='100%' height='100%' src='data:application/pdf;base64, " +
        encodeURI(base64PdfDoc) + "'></iframe>"
    );
}
```

Javascript called from Backend code

```
await JsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("openPdf", pdfContent);
```

Trying to bind in html as well but not working

```
                    <object width="100%" height="100%" data="data:application/pdf;base64,@base64pdfString" type="application/pdf" class="internal"
                    <embed src="data:application/pdf;base64,@base64courierlogpdfString" type="application/pdf" />
</object>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Incorporating the same concept, I've implemented a solution. Since the backend API was returning a response in base64 format and file size was more than 2MB, It was not able to load in iframe, Showing as blank screen but when I converted the file to a blob and generated a blob URL and mapped to iframe then it's loading.
Steps:

- Get the file stream response from API
- received the file stream in blazor backend and return the base 64 file to javascript method.
- In Javascript convert the based 64 file to blob and create a blob url and mapped to iframe.

```
function base64ToBlob(base64Data, contentType) {
    contentType = contentType || '';
    var sliceSize = 1024;
    var byteCharacters = atob(base64Data);
    var byteArrays = [];

    for (var offset = 0; offset < byteCharacters.length; offset += sliceSize) {
        var slice = byteCharacters.slice(offset, offset + sliceSize);
        var byteNumbers = new Array(slice.length);
        for (var i = 0; i < slice.length; i++) {
            byteNumbers[i] = slice.charCodeAt(i);
        }
        var byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);
        byteArrays.push(byteArray);
    }

    var blob = new Blob(byteArrays, { type: contentType });
    return blob;
}

function openPdf(base64Data) {
    var blob = base64ToBlob(base64Data, 'application/pdf');
    var link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    //link.download = filename;
    //link.click();

    var left = window.screen.width;
        left = left > 0 ? left / 4 : 0;
        let pdfWindow = window.open("", 'winname', 'directories=no,titlebar=no,toolbar=no,location=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=no,width=800,height=750, top = 0, left=' + left);
    pdfWindow.document.write(
        "<iframe width='100%' height='100%' src='" + link.href + "'></iframe>");
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I have updated my answer mentioning more clear steps. Thank you so much for your comment .

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript interop is not feasible to pass a very large string. Because Blazor and the underlying `System.Text.Json` library have a limit on the size of a single JSON value passed through `JSInterop`, this limit is to prevent performance issues and potential browser crashes.

So we can bypass this limitation by adding a `Controller` to `Blazor Server Project` and then using blobs in javascript, as detailed below.

Step 1.  [Prerequisites, add support for controllers in the Blazor project.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77147832/7687666)

Step 2. The structure of my project.

[image]

Step 3. [Download the pdf.js here.](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/pdf.js/3.11.174) And use it like my project.

Step 4. pdfViewer.js.

```
function showPdfInIframe(pdfUrl) {
    fetch(pdfUrl)
        .then(response => response.blob())
        .then(blob => {
            const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            document.getElementById('pdfIframe').src = url;
        })
        .catch(error => console.error('Error loading the PDF:', error));
}
```

Step 5. `HomeController.cs`.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace BlazorApp3.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        [HttpGet("{fileName}")]
        public IActionResult Get(string fileName)
        {
            var filePath = Path.Combine("wwwroot", "pdf", fileName);
            if (!System.IO.File.Exists(filePath))
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            return File(stream, "application/pdf", fileName);
        }
    }
}
```

Step 6. PdfDemo.razor.

```
@page "/pdfdemo"
@inject IJSRuntime JSRuntime


<h3>PDF.js in Blazor Demo</h3>


<iframe id="pdfIframe" style="width:100%; height:600px;" frameborder="0"></iframe>

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="LoadPDF">Load PDF</button>

@code {
    private async Task LoadPDF()
    {
        var fileName = "200MB-TESTFILE.ORG.pdf"; 
        await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("showPdfInIframe", $"/api/home/{fileName}");
    }
}
```

**Test Result**

[image]

Comment: Thak you for the time and effort you put into crafting such a thorough and informative answer. Incorporating the same concept, I've successfully implemented a solution. Since the backend API was returning a response in base64 format, I converted it to a blob and generated a blob URL. Subsequently, I mapped this URL within an iframe to display the content seamlessly.